# Quiero operar mas de 2 valores en mi calculadora Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, switch

He hecho una calculadora, aqui esta solo la suma para simplificar mi duda, pero solo puedo sumar 2 numeros/valores, declarando las variables operadorA y operadorB

Cuando apreto el "+" solo me suma los 2 ultimos valores que haya ingresado, lo cual es correcto segun mi codigo, lo que me pregunto es **¿Hay alguna forma de que al apretar "=" me sume todos los numeros ingresados?**

Por ejemplo ingreso 20, doy click +, Ingreso 30 doy click +, Ingreso 40 doy click +,

Me deberia salir 90, ¿Se puede hacer asi? o debo ingresar un "operadorX" para cada valor que haga?

Espero haberme explicado bien

Este es mi ajustes.js

```
let pantalla = document.getElementById('pantalla');

let operadorA;
let operadorB;
let operacion;

function init(){

    let reset = document.getElementById('reiniciar');
    let suma = document.getElementById('suma');
    let igual = document.getElementById('igual');
    
    let uno = document.getElementById('uno');
    let dos = document.getElementById('dos');
    let tres = document.getElementById('tres');
    let cuatro = document.getElementById('cuatro');
    let cinco = document.getElementById('cinco');
    let seis = document.getElementById('seis');
    let siete = document.getElementById('siete');
    let ocho = document.getElementById('ocho');
    let nueve = document.getElementById('nueve');
    let cero = document.getElementById('cero');

    
    uno.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "1"
        : pantalla.textContent += "1";
    }

    dos.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "2"
        : pantalla.textContent += "2";
    }
    tres.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "3"
        : pantalla.textContent += "3";
    }
    cuatro.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "4"
        : pantalla.textContent += "4";
    }
    cinco.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "5"
        : pantalla.textContent += "5";
    }
    seis.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "6"
        : pantalla.textContent += "6";
    }
    siete.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "7"
        : pantalla.textContent += "7";
    }
    ocho.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "8"
        : pantalla.textContent += "8";
    }
    nueve.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "9"
        : pantalla.textContent += "9";
    }

    cero.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent === '0'
        ? pantalla.textContent = "0"
        : pantalla.textContent += "0";
    }

    reset.onclick = function(e){
        pantalla.textContent = "";
    }

    suma.onclick = function(e){
        operadorA = pantalla.textContent;
        operacion = "+",
        limpiar();
    }

    igual.onclick = function(e){
        operadorB = pantalla.textContent;
        resolver();
    }

}

function limpiar(){
    pantalla.textContent = "";
}

function resetear(){
    limpiar();
    operadorA = 0;
    operadorB = 0;
    operacion = "";
}


function resolver(){
    let res = 0;

    switch(operacion){
        case "+":
            res = parseFloat(operadorA) + parseFloat(operadorB);
            break;
        // Aca van las otras operaciones, pero asi es mas facil de enseñar
        }

        operadorA = res;

        resetear();

        pantalla.textContent = res;
    }


init();
```

Esta es la estructura base de mi calculadora

```
<body>
    <p>Calculadora funcional</p>
    <div class="numeros">

        <span class="pantalla" id="pantalla"></span>
        <div>
            <div id="uno" class="numero">1</div>
            <div id="dos" class="numero">2</div>
            <div id="tres" class="numero">3</div>
            <div id="suma" class="signos">+</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="cuatro" class="numero">4</div>
            <div id="cinco" class="numero">5</div>
            <div id="seis" class="numero">6</div>
            <!-- <div id="resta" class="signos">-</div> -->
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="siete" class="numero">7</div>
            <div id="ocho" class="numero">8</div>
            <div id="nueve" class="numero">9</div>
            <!-- <div id="multiplicacion" class="signos">X</div> -->
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="reiniciar" class="signos">C</div>
            <div id="cero" class="numero">0</div>
            <div id="igual" class="signos">=</div>
            <!-- <div id="division" class="signos">/</div> -->
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajustes.js"></script>
</body>
```

Este es el css

```
.pantalla{
    background: #AEB3AF;
    font-size: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 550px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.numero, .signos{
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 2px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #FEF0F0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.signos {
    background: #9D8D8D;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.numero:hover, .signos:hover{
    background: #473E3E;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.numeros {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #CE1414;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Jose Godoy Cebreros, se me ocurre que un buen enfoque, sería guardar los números y las operaciones en dos List, cuando se aprieta el botón **=**, simplemente recorres el List **números**, sacas los dos primeros números, la primer **operación**, haces la cuenta, la guardas en un List **auxiliar**, si el List **números** tiene más valores, repites el proceso, usando el tercer valor de **números** el primero de **auxiliar** y el segundo de operación... espero haber sido claro.

Comment: me podrias dar un pequeño ejemplo por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cantNumeros = 0;
let cantOperaciones = 0;
let auxiliar = "";
let numeros = [];
let operaciones = [];

// a medida que pulsa las teclas numéricas, va llamando a esta
// función, que construye el numero a utilizar y lo presenta.
function recibeNumeros( numeroIngresado ) {
    auxiliar = numeroIngresado + auxiliar;
    mostrarEnPantalla( auxiliar );
}

function mostrarEnPantalla( numero ) {
    pantalla.textContent = numero;
}

// esta función recibe las operaciones ingresadas, cuando la 
// operacion no es **"="**, agrega la nueva operacion al array de
// estas y el numero almacenado en **auxiliar** al array de numeros.
// luego resetea cantOperaciones, cantNumeros y auxiliar.
function recibeOperaciones( operacionIngresada ) {
    if( operacionIngresada == "=" ) {
        resuelve();
    }
    else {
        operaciones.push( operacionIngresada );
        numeros.push( auxiliar );
        cantOperaciones++;
        cantNumeros++;
        auxiliar = "";
    }
}

// acá tomamos el primer valor de **numeros**, lo guardamos en una
// variable y entramos al bucle, en este, se toma el valor de la 
// segunda variable almacenada en **numeros** (hablando de la primer
// iteración), y el primer valor de **operaciones**, con ellos llama
// a la función **operacion** y asigna su return a **numeroA**, de 
// esta manera queda preparada para la siguiente operación, y de no 
// haberla, devuelve su valor.
function resuelve() {
    let numeroA = numeros[ 0 ];
    for( int i = 1; i <= cantNumeros.length; i++ ) {
        numeroA = operacion( numeroA, numeros[ i ], operaciones[ i - 1 ] );
    }
    mostrarEnPantalla( numeroA );

    numeros = []
    operaciones = []
    cantOperaciones = 0;
    cantNumeros = 0;
    auxiliar = "";
}

function operacion( numeroA, numeroB, operacion ) {
    if( operacion == "+" ) {
        return numeroA + numeroB;
    }
    else if( operacion == "-" ) {
        return numeroA - numeroB;
    }
    else if( operacion == "/" ) {
        return numeroA / numeroB;
    }
    else if( operacion == "*" ) {
        return numeroA * numeroB;
    }
    
}
```

espero que te sirva como guia.

Comment: Es posible que se me haya **caido** algún error, no pude probarlo, espero que a pesar de eso te sirva como idea general, un punto de partida.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys, hola, tu sugerencia me deja un poco descolocado, soy de los que leen, y he leido **como contestar**, **cuando votar negativo**, etc, miro mi respuesta, y creo que está dentro de lo que se considera correcto, el OP, me pidió un ejemplo, se lo dí, creo que bastante bien explicado... no se, me podrías orientar en que estoy fallando?, porque de verdad no lo veo, desde ya gracias.